# PyCharm remote debugging Django app does not stop at breakpoints

Tags: python, django, vagrant, pycharm, remote-debugging

I have a PyCharm / Django project that is configured with Vagrant as a remote interpreter. I have configured the Run/Debug Configurations so that I can run the django development server or run it in debug mode from the PyCharm toolbar. The problem is when I run the application in debug mode, it does not stop at the breakpoints I have set in any python file. If I set a breakpoint in a view that calls a template, it will stop at the first Jinja template tag that is found. If the view does not render a template, such as an API endpoint that returns a Json response, the application will not stop at any breakpoints.

I when I run in debug mode I get the following output from the console:

```
ssh://vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222/opt/virtualenv/bin/python -u /home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support --client '0.0.0.0' --port 59503 --file /opt/sakas.co/mezzanine_cms/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
pydev debugger: process 2873 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 145.971)
pydev debugger: process 2880 is connecting
```

So its connecting successfully. I believe that I have the remote interpreter set up correctly because I can run and work on the application fine. I'm just not sure why it will only break in template files and not in python files.

Its also worth noting that this project uses Django 1.7.9, and python2.7

Comment: Which PyCharm Version r u using: make sure support of Django . Use PyCharm Professional

Comment: Possibly related to the same [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19342) as this, but this was regarding template breakpoints. (This will be fixed in 2016.1.4)

Comment: @MushahidKhan - Community supports breakpoints too, its template debugging that pro gives and by the sounds of it they might be working. Jon Sakas, if its not the above, have you muted the breakpoints?

Comment: Have the same problem. Seeing debug connected,  but not stop in the breakpoints. Every breakpoint is enabled. Have you figured out the solution? Or know how to trace it?